# Why does my Dell laptop touchpad stop physically clicking when I'm at altitude?

Tags: laptop, touchpad

I have a Dell XPS 9560 - the touchpad will physically click when the bottom edge is depressed, except when my laptop is at high-altitude[1] the touchpad physically stops clicking and pressing down on the bottom edge doesn't have any tactile response and I have to press down so hard it hurts my fingers before the OS detects a click action (I have "tap to click" disabled, so it's only "click-to-click").

I verified it's independent of the laptop's attitude or orientation (as inside 
 an aircraft cabinet in-flight the cabin is angled upwards) - so I assume that maybe the physical clicker is not using a spring or microswitch, but instead using something like an air-bubble under a membrane like cheap keyboard switches - except surely if the air pressure is lower, then the trapped air-bubble would be bigger?

(I know there are reports of the laptop battery swelling/expanding which causes the touchpad to pop-up - but the touchpad looks and feels normal and there's no sign of battery swelling - and the touchpad becomes clickable once I get to a lower altitude).

[1] e.g. atop a mountain, driving through a mountain pass, on an aircraft when the cabin is pressurized (as cabins aren't pressurized to ground-level pressure, but something like 11,000ft pressure)

Comment: *Something* is expanding at low pressure. It could be rubber standoffs or sealed hollow plastic parts. Membrane switches can create a seal to the surface that they are against and, as you say the air bubble will be "bigger" with an effective high pressure inside making it more difficult to compress as required. The only way to know for sure would be to dismantle the trackpad area to find out how the "clicker" works and what could be creating a sealed area and break that seal as carefully as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was the battery swelling. Dell did a warranty replacement of the battery and it's been fine ever since.